# Facebook Swift SDK login won't open native dialog

Tags: swift, facebook

I am integrating the [Facebook Swift SDK](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-sdk-swift) into my app, and I followed theses steps:

Install dependency with CocoaPods - `pod 'FacebookLogin'`

Add the following to Info.plist:

```
<key>FacebookAppID</key>
<string>**my_app_id**</string>
<key>FacebookDisplayName</key>
<string>**my_app_name**</string>
<key>CFBundleURLTypes</key>
<array>
  <dict>
    <key>CFBundleURLSchemes</key>
    <array>
      <string>fb**my_app_id**</string>
    </array>
  </dict>
</array>
<key>LSApplicationQueriesSchemes</key>
<array>
  <string>fbapi</string>
  <string>fb-messenger-api</string>
  <string>fbauth2</string>
  <string>fbshareextension</string>
</array>
```

Add to `AppDelegate`:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
  SDKApplicationDelegate.shared.application(application, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: launchOptions)

  return true
}

func application(_ app: UIApplication, open url: URL, options: [UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey : Any] = [:]) -> Bool {
  return SDKApplicationDelegate.shared.application(app, open: url, options: options)
}
```

Call in a view controller:

```
LoginManager()
  .logIn([.publicProfile, .email], viewController: self) { result in
  switch result {
  case .failed(let error):
    print(error)
  case .cancelled:
    print("User cancelled login.")
  case .success(_, _, let accessToken):
    print("User logged in")
  }
}
```

And that's about it. When I click the button, I expected the native login to load, switching to the FB app and then back to my app. However it never happens, and a webpage is loaded on a `SFSafariViewController`.

I also tried forcing the `loginBehavior` to `.native`, and all the other options, but changing it has absolutely no effect.

What else do I need to do in order to make the native login work?

Comment: did you set 'fbLoginButton.delegate = self' ?

Comment: I am using a custom button

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found [this post](https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2015/10/29/Facebook-Login-iOS9) from FB Developers blog where they say that the Safari VC has a better click-through rate when compared to the fast app switch on iOS 9 and above, and decided to make that the default behavior.

> We've been monitoring data and CTRs for over 250 apps over the last 6 weeks since iOS 9 launched. The click-through rate (CTR) of SVC Login outperforms the CTR of app-switch Login and is improving at 3x the rate of the app-switch experience. This indicates that the SVC experience is better for people and developers today, and will likely be the best solution in the long run. For this reason, the latest Facebook SDK for iOS uses SVC as the default experience for Login.